# pass input value of radio as parameter into google.script.run.withSuccessHandler

Tags: google-apps-script

How to pass input value of radio as parameter into .getStudents()

```
  <input type="radio"
         name="orderList"
         value="orderByAdmissionDate"
         onClick>
         Data de Cadastro

  <input type="radio"
         name="orderList"
         value="orderByName">
         Nome       

  <input id="submit_getStudents"
         type="submit"   
   onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).getStudents();"
         value="Listar";>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this modification? I think that there are several solutions for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Modification points:

- Add `<form>` tag.
- When the button is clicked, the values are sent to GAS using `this.parentNode`.

#### Modified script:

HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type="radio"
         name="orderList"
         value="orderByAdmissionDate"
         onClick>
         Data de Cadastro

  <input type="radio"
         name="orderList"
         value="orderByName">
         Nome

  <input id="submit_getStudents"
         type="submit"   
   onclick="event.preventDefault();google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).getStudents(this.parentNode);"
         value="Listar";>
</form>

<script>
  function createTable(e) {
    // do something
  }
</script>
```

GAS:

```
function getStudents(e) {
  // do something
}
```

#### Result:

- When "Data de Cadastro" is checked, `e` of `getStudents(e)` returns `{"orderList":"orderByAdmissionDate"}`.
- When "Nome" is checked, `e` of `getStudents(e)` returns `{"orderList":"orderByName"}`.

#### Note:

- Before you run the script, please add the function of `createTable`.

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thaks for your reply.

I tried : getStudents(this.parentNode) and got this error in Google Browser Developers Tools: Uncaught Error: Failed due to illegal value in property: 0

I tried too: getStudents("this.parentNode");  getStudents(' "this.parentNode" ');  getStudents(' "&this.parentNode&" ') - not pass e value to GAS.

Comment: @jcom I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. Can you provide your whole script? Because when only your snippet is tried, it works in my environment. Can you do it?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jaLVvbkVrZNF3ydm0H0lyjVkrnRyxfk9bC2maEUkyp8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @jcom Thank you for replying. In your script, I cannot see the script of GAS side. And it seems that my answer is not reflected to your script. So I cannot understand about the issue. I'm really sorry for my poor skill. For example, using the simple snippet, how about testing what you want to do?